# Forcing Holomap to render as a slider instead of a dropdown menu

Tags: bokeh, holoviews

Is there a way to explicitly tell Holoviews that a particular holomap ought to be a slider instead of a drop-down? I have a kdim which is a datetime object, grouped by year, and since there is an ordering, is there a way to force it to plot the holomap as a slider instead of a drop-down?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by getting a player widget (has a nice slider plus play buttons). To do this, use the following line at the top of a cell:

```
%output holomap='scrubber'
```

I remember seeing this in one of the github issues on the holoviews repo. I recommend searching both the closed and open issues on the repo when you are stuck on something new. It is a rich source of information: https://github.com/ioam/holoviews/issues

Cheers